# Adding gradle dependency from git project

Tags: android, github, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add [this](https://github.com/Yalantis/Context-Menu.Android) project to my gradle project in Android studio. I tried using Gradle git plugin as described [here](http://bat-cha.github.io/gradle-plugin-git-dependencies/) but Gradle says it can not find those files even though i placed folders inside app folder in my project. I added in dependencies in gradle.build file to include project in build but no luck, it just says project does not exist. Does anyone know good tutorial or have any suggestion about this?

Answer (score 2):

You could register the repository as a submodule like this

```
$ git submodule add my_sub_project_git_url my-sub-project
```

Then include the project in your settings.gradle file which should look like this

```
include ':my-app', ':my-sub-project'
```

Finally, compile the project as a dependency in your application build.gradle file like this

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':my-sub-project')
}
```

Then, when cloning your project, you will only have to add the option --recursive to make git automatically clone the root repository, and all its submodules.

```
git clone --recursive my_sub_project_git_url
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is useful, but i was looking for simple including. If no one answers else I will mark your answer.